# Passing Clientside Geocoded Result using POST

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I am building a page which contains a form with 2 text input boxes, `search_term` and `search_location`. This allows the site user to search for a place near a particular location. To prevent hitting the API limit, I need to geocode **clientside** the user-inputted address from `search_location` text input box to a LatLng coordinate, which will be passed in `$_POST[]` to a PHP function which will access the relevant records in the MySQL database.

This is how I think it should work:

1. User types in address/zipcode into `search_location` text input box & a keyword into the `search_term` text input box.
2. When the `Submit` button is clicked, a JS event handler will use the Google Geocoder API to geocode the result and return the `LatLng` coordinates.
3. The `LatLng` coordinates is passed to the PHP function which accesses it as a `POST` variable, and access the database to retrieve the required results.

**The Question:**
I do not know how I can submit the form after getting the geocoded result from Google Geocoder API so I can pass the `LatLng` coordinates along in `POST`. At the moment, the form passes the user-inputted values in `search_term` and `search_location` input boxes.

Comment: Can you add hidden form field and save LatLng coordinates to it? Or you can't alter form code?

Comment: yes i can alter the form code and add a hidden form field. my javascript aint too good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to set 2 hidden fields (one for lat and another for lng unless you want to save them as 1 string) and save the coords to it and then submit the form:

your form:

```
<form id='codeForm' action='some.php'>
<input type='text' name='search_location'>
<input type='text' name='search_term'>
<input type='hidden' name='lat'>
<input type='hidden' name='lng'>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress()">
</form>
```

In the form I used a button type if you use a submit button you need to cancel the submit action until google returns a response or use onSubmit() event for the form.

Your geocode js function:

```
 function codeAddress() {
myForm =  document.forms["codeForm"]
    //get the address
        var address = myForm.elements["search_location"].value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    //geocode was successful      
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
//grab the lat and long
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat
    lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng
   myForm.elements["lat"].value=lat
   myForm.elements["lng"].value=lng
//submit form
     myForm.submit();      
          } else {
//geocode failed
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: @luke_mclachlan please refer to the line in my answer about using a submit button where I recommend to cancel the submit until geocoder returns. If you use a button type to trigger geocoding, the geocode.js function takes care of "delay" in geocoding. Creating a timeout does not solve your problem only potentially delays it. If you want to be clever about it you can also use jquery.when() function.

Comment: Good suggestion regarding .when(). I found that even with the button, instead of submit, that the values were not being passed in time.

Answer (score 0):

My slightly modified code to Michael's above, which unfortunately doesn't work out of the box. I feel it's important to highlight this, because Google takes me to this post when I search for "geocode client side hidden fields". I'm taking the following code directly from my site, which uses $_GET, but it works either way. We start with the form:

```
<form type="get" id='codeForm' action='index.php'>
<input type='text' name='search_location' id='search_location'>
<input type='text' name='search_term'>
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="submitform">
<input type='text' name='search_term'>
</form>
```

As you can see, I've taken away the hidden lat and lng input fields from the form and appended them with jquery below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function codeAddress() {
    myForm =  document.forms["codeForm"];
    //get the address
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('search_location').value;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address, componentRestrictions:{country:"uk"}}, function(results, status) {
        //geocode was successful      
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            //grab the lat and long
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            $("#codeForm").append("<input type='hidden' name='lat' value='" + lat + "' />");
            var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $("#codeForm").append("<input type='hidden' name='lng' value='" + lng + "' />");

            //submit form

        } else {
        //geocode failed
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#codeForm').submit(function(e) {
        var form = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        codeAddress();
        setTimeout(function () {
            form.submit();
        }, 1000); // in milliseconds
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The important point about my code is that I have added a setTimeout delay, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15697464/3842368) on SO. Without the delay, I found that the values in Michal's solution above were not being appended in time.

As a footnote, I know that I could improve upon the mix of javascript and jquery in my solution, but importantly it's a working example, and it's up to each and everyone to modify should they wish.